# Starting letter of itemization

Tags: punctuation, capitalization

Here is an example sentence:

"With the help of their company, (1) we will ... And, ... (2) they will ..."

There are whole sentences separated with `.` in (1) and (2). I would like to know if `w` of `we` (similarly for `t` of `they`) should be uppercase or lowercase?

Comment: It might help if you filled in the gaps. If you need to use numbers, why not make it into a proper list - something like (1) We will do X. (2) They will do X ?

Comment: Bulleted paragraphs would be better; they're ideal for complex but related parts of a single project or agreement. Plus you'd need more than one sentence anyway. As for capitalization, do it whatever way you want; that's marketing, not grammar.

Comment: Could you make those real example sentences, please?